# HTTPS render html files with Node Js

Tags: node.js, https

I tried to set up a HTTPS server in localhost, however I do not know how to render a html file when the server is running. Below is my code:

```
var https = require('https'); var fs = require('fs');

var options = {   key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),   
                 cert: fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem') };

var a = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {   
        console.log('Server is starting');           
       res.writeHead(200);                                            
    // res.end("hello world\n");
       res.render('index.html');

}).listen(8000);
```

I can access to the localhost, but whenever I tried to render a html files,I got an error message of '.render() is not a function', what is the alternative to 'call' a html files when the server is running. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the filesystem.

This way, you will prepare the file, store it inside `content` and send the full html file to your client:

```js
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (error, content) {
   if (error) {
      response.writeHead(500);
      response.end('Error');
   } else {
      response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
      response.end(content, 'utf-8');
   }
});
```

You don't have the `render` function in pure node.js. if you want to use it, you need to use express.js.

The code I wrote need to be inside your `createServer` function.

Comment: Hi, these codes work for me, thank you so much! thanks!!